# Make Paths Contiguous in SVG

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have an SVG that has some thick strokes, when these are removed gaps in the SVG are revealed, as so:

[image]

See gaps on the left hand side. Is there anyway to automatically, or quickly expand the paths so they "snap" to a neighbours border, thus removing the gaps?

Comment: The best I can find is yo use Inkscape's outset, but I can't find anything that will let me control the level at which at is being expanded.

Comment: how many paths like these do you have, is it a big svg? if you mean the non coincident paths in picture 1 this happens cause they are different paths and they shouldn't be, you will have to "print" the svg to the resolution you want and then use the exactly same path in the opposite direction. if you mean the white spots on picture 2, that's path segments you will need to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to correct the source data, then I'd suggest an algorithm that detects intersections, extracts matching sub-paths and then replaces one of the sub-paths with its twin.

If you simply want it to look the right way visually, you can use a filter to extract the white areas, recolor them blue and composite them back. That's pretty easy to do. Adjust the R G and B in the color matrix below to the rgb you want on a 0 to 1 scale (aka pure blue would be 0 0 1 and mid grey would be 0.5  0.5 0.5)

```
  <filter id="recolor-white" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" in="SourceGraphic" result="lumMap"/>
    <feComponentTransfer in="lumMap" result="highlightMask">
       <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>

     <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic" in2="highlightMask" result="highlights"/>

        <feColorMatrix in="highlights" result="bluepatch" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 R
                                                             0 0 0 0 G
                                                             0 0 0 0 B
                                                             0 0 0 1 0"/>

  <feComposite operator="over" in="bluepatch" in2="SourceGraphic" result="final"/>

</filter>
```